# AWS Device Farm + Espresso: Running Espresso Instrumentation Test involving Native JNI method call in AWS Device Farm

Tags: java, android, jenkins, android-espresso, aws-device-farm

I am using Jenkins' **Run Test on AWS Device Farm** post build action to run Espresso Android Instrumentation test in the devices in Device Farm. The app uses a native JNI Library to create TIFF Images out of JPEGS.

However, as soon as the code for executing the native function gets executed, the app crashes. Even if I am just running the app in one of the devices in the Device Farm, the app crashes when I click on the button that calls the native JNI function.

I am getting following error in the logs:
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "rand" referenced by "libtiff.so"...

Also getting following JNI related logs at an earlier point of time, when things were getting initialized

- No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0 skipping init
- Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
- CheckJNI is OFF

I want to know if JNI library loading is by default disabled in the AWS Device Farm. If yes, is there a way to enable them. If JNI Libraries are supported by default, can someone please point me in the right direction so that I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you learn an outcome to this issue? Did you try other cloud services?

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm Team.

1. JNI library loading is not disabled on Device Farm.
2. One thing that may be a potential cause of the issue that you are seeing is that we resign apps at our end when uploaded which may break things like Google maps. Refer FAQ "Do you modify my app?" https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faq/

Also make sure that you are able to load this app on a real device locally and launch it successfully. This will give you a baseline to compare.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NikofTime.
The app works on a real device locally.
The JNI is not using any of google play services. It is a simple image compression library written in native. Not sure why it would crash for that. Any pointers would really be appreciated. Thanks again :)

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is any setting that needs to be enabled on the device? Apart from the settings and resigning I can't think of any reason that the app would crash unless there was a compatibility bug that was actually caught because the app was tested on a different device.

Comment: There is no special setting. It's a simple Image Compression App. The crash is happening on all the devices I have tested on so far in AWS Device Farm. So not sure if it is device specific